# How to select a tr row in a table?

Tags: jquery

Can you help me? I want use this code for a table.

By clicking ".click" (in a td in the tr-row before) the (next tr ".showme") should toggle the class.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".click").click(function() {
     $(this).parent().find(".showme").toggleClass( 'Active Inactive' );
  });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table> 
    <tr> 
        <td>1</td> 
        <td class="click">2</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr class="showme Active"colspan="4">
        <td>slidein</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>1</td> 
        <td class="click">2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="showme Active"colspan="4">
    <td>slidein</td>
   </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Please post your markup too.

Comment: Remove `,` from toggle class `toggleClass( 'Active Inactive' );`

Comment: Sorry, it doesn´t work, the site says "my code is too long" :-(

Comment: just put table structure with few trs so that we can understand the structure and help you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:  you can use `closest` to get the parent TR and then use `next` to get the next tr with showme class. Also, remove comma in toggleclass method and use space for separation

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".click").on('click',function() {
     $(this).closest('tr').next('tr.showme').toggleClass( 'Active Inactive' );
  });
   });
```

```css
.Active {
   color:green;
}

.Inactive {
   color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table> 
    <tr> 
        <td>1</td> 
        <td class="click">2</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr class="showme Active" colspan="2">
        <td>slidein</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>1</td> 
        <td class="click">2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="showme Active" colspan="2">
    <td>slidein</td>
   </tr> 
</table>
```

NOTE: you have used colspan="4" but maximum columns are 2 so i have changes it to colspan="2" to make table structure without error

**UPDATE**
Please find the answer to your query where you can make use of `nextAll` with `:first` selector restriction so that you can toggle Class for the first matching element. This will remove restriction of next element position.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".click1").click(function() {
  $('.clicked').not(this).removeClass('clicked');
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
  var $next = $(this).parents("tr").nextAll(".showme1:first");
  $next.toggleClass("Active Inactive");
  $('tr.Active').not($next).removeClass('Active');
  });

   $(".click2").click(function() { 
  $('.clicked').not(this).removeClass('clicked');
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
   var $next = $(this).parents("tr").nextAll(".showme2:first");
  $next.toggleClass("Active Inactive");
  $('tr.Active').not($next).removeClass('Active');
  });

   $(".click3").click(function() {
  $('.clicked').not(this).removeClass('clicked');
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
  var $next = $(this).parents("tr").nextAll(".showme3:first");
  $next.toggleClass("Active Inactive");
  $('tr.Active').not($next).removeClass('Active');
  });
});
```

```css
.showme1, .showme2, .showme3 {
  display: none;
}
.Active {
  display: block;
}
.click1, .click2, .click3 {
  color: red;
}
.clicked {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="click1">1</td>
    <td class="click2">2</td>
    <td class="click3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="showme1 Inactive" colspan="3"><td>showme1</td></tr>
  <tr class="showme2 Inactive" colspan="3"><td>showme2</td></tr>
  <tr class="showme3 Inactive" colspan="3"><td>showme3</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="click1">1</td>
    <td class="click2">2</td>
    <td class="click3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="showme1 Inactive" colspan="3"><td>showme1</td></tr>
  <tr class="showme2 Inactive" colspan="3"><td>showme2</td></tr>
  <tr class="showme3 Inactive" colspan="3"><td>showme3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What can I do, when there are many tr -rows? How can I handle this?
(not the next, rather the second or third row)

Comment: can you give me some sample code so that i can suggest you the solution. any jsfiddle or codepen or any live code would be fine

Comment: I could not update code pen so edited the answer above by adding new code snippet. Please refer that. If you find this answer useful then you can upvote and accept the answer

Comment: Thank you so much. Now, I have updated my pen. Is there a way that close the active tr, when I open an other?
In addition I want add a class to the active td (when I click on it, it changes to class "blue" and by clicking another I change back to "red"?

https://codepen.io/tho-zei/pen/XWrPgJb

Comment: Thank you so much. It looks very good. The only thing, it doesn't change back to red, when nothing is active.

Comment: resolved that issue too, please check updated answer

Comment: I find a little issue. After some clicks "showme" becomes the class active and Inactive at once.

Comment: have you modified the code and put some code which takes time to execute because i am not able to reproduce this issue. If you can create codepen i can check that

Comment: I have updated the codepen
https://codepen.io/tho-zei/pen/XWrPgJb
You see it, when you open the Codeinspector from your browser.
Thank you so much for helping me :-)

Comment: I got the issue, you need to replace `$('tr.Active').not($next).removeClass('Active');` by `$('tr.Active').not($next).toggleClass('Active Inactive');`. removeClass is removing previously active element and toggleClass add both classes when clicked second time.... my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to check which tr is open and close it, if open another?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parents("tr")` and `next(".showme")`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".click").click(function() {
     $(this).parents("tr").next(".showme").toggleClass("Active Inactive");
  });
});
```

```css
.showme {
  display: none;
}
.Active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="click">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="showme Active" colspan="4"><td>slidein</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="click">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="showme Active" colspan="4"><td>slidein</td></tr>
</table>
```